# Django Rest Framework: URL for associated elements

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following API endpoints already created and working fine:

**urls.py:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'countries', views.CountriesViewSet,
                base_name='datapoints')
router.register(r'languages', views.LanguageViewSet,
                base_name='records')
```

Now, I need to create a new endpoint, where I can retrieve the countries associated with one language (let's suppose that one country has just one associated language).

For that purpose, I would create a new endpoint with the following URL pattern:

```
/myApp/languages/<language_id>/countries/
```

How could I express that pattern with the `DefaultRouter` that I'm already using?

Comment: `router.register(r'languages/<int:language_id>/countries/', views.LanguageViewSet,
                base_name='language_contries')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from [DRF routers' extra actions capabilities](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions) and especially the `@action` method decorator:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

from .serializers import CountrySerializer


class LanguageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # ...

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get']):
    def countries(self, request, pk=None):
        language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=pk)
        # Note:
        # In the next line, have in mind the
        # related_name
        # specified in models
        # between Country & Language
        countries = language.countries.all()
        # ___________________^

        serializer = CountrySerializer(countries, many=True)

        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Having this, your current router specification should stay the same and you will have your desired route already registered.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the DRF router extra actions. Thank you @wencakisa!