# Django Rest Framework: URL with nested resources and two ID's

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with DRF and I'm struggling to create a URL like this:

```
/myApp/languages/<language_id>/countries/<country_id>/
```

Thanks to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943000/django-rest-framework-url-for-associated-elements), I know that I can easily use the `@action` method decorator within [DRF router's extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions),  to handle URLs with this format:

```
/myApp/languages/<language_id>/countries/
```

However, I haven't found a way to register the new URL that I need, where I include an ID for the second resource:

```
/myApp/languages/<language_id>/countries/<country_id>/
```

How can I do it with DRF?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
/myApp/languages/<language_id>/countries/<country_id>/
```

Please try below:

```
/myApp/languages/countries/<language_id>/<country_id>/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate package [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) recommended in the Django REST Framework documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers).

Your solution could look like:

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers


router = routers.DefaultRouter()

# registering language routes
router.register('languages', views.LanguageViewSet, base_name='languages')

# configuring nested language routes
language_router = routers.NestedDefaultRouter(router, "languages", lookup="language")

# registering nested countries routes with language router
language_router.register('countries', views.CountriesViewSet, base_name='language-countries')

urlpatterns = router.urls + language_router.urls
```